# How to run linux like cp command on same server..but copy says it does not find remote server

Tags: ansible, copy

I am trying to emulate scenario of copying local file from one directory to another directory on same machine..but ansible copy command is looking for remote server always..

code I am using

```
  - name: Configure Create directory
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  vars:
    customer_folder: "{{ customer }}"
  tasks:
     - file:
         path: /opt/scripts/{ customer_folder }}
         state: directory

     - copy:
         src: /home/centos/absample.txt
         dest: /opt/scripts/{{ customer_folder }}
```

~

I am running this play book like 
`ansible-playbook ab_deploy.yml --extra-vars "customer=ab"`

So two problem i am facing
It should create a directory called ab under /opt/scripts/ but it creating folder as { customer_folder }}..its not taking ab as name of directory

second, copy as i read documentation, copy only work to copy files from local to remote machine, But i want is simply copy from local to local..

how can i achieve this..might be silly, i am just trying out things

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it..i used cmd under shell module then it worked.